# convert JSON to Adob.recordset or retrieve Adob.recordset from webservice

Tags: node.js, vba, typescript

I'm using a legacy VBA macros application to send web requests to an API that returns json data. The VBA app requires a Adob.recordset as a return method for the function I'm looking to replace with the webservice call.

I've managed to get the API to return a JSON payload of all of the relevant records, but I'm not finding good ways to convert JSON into a recordset on the VB6 end. Is there a way to either pass a recordset from the nodejs/typescript API or convert JSON to a recordset on the VBA end?

Comment: Can the json be written into a 2D array? In which case you might be able to substitute that array for rng.value in the following: https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/vba-trick-of-the-week-range-to-recordset-without-making-connection/  ?

Comment: Well, JSON and VB6/VBA don't go well together. I only ever ran across one decent JSON library (two, in fact, but one is based on the other): [#1](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/720368/VB-JSON-Parser-Improved-Performance) and [#2](http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html). You still have to create an ADODB.Recordset from the data yourself. If a commercial component is an option, there's one from [Chilkat](https://www.example-code.com/vb6/json.asp)

Comment: @QHarr Actually my project was using  the record set in a lot of functions like this 
 Set rst = cnt.Execute("Select * From Tbl Where ID=C_ID))
        If rst.EOF = False Then
            While rst.EOF = False Wend 
Now I'm using a separate web service that return json object so i need to optimize the changes in the vba project because it's a live and sensitive project

Comment: https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas

Comment: You can create a standalone recordset and populate it from a JSON object, provided the JSON data  has a "tabular" data structure.  https://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3846361/Create-In-Memory-ADO-Recordsets.htm

Comment: Is it VBA or VB6?

Comment: @StayOnTarget it's a Vba macros